# How to get downloading stats for angular2 npm package?

Tags: angular, download, npm

I', preparing a presentation for a conference and confused by one thing... I can't find downloading statistics for angular2 npm package! Actually I'm trying to find here https://npm-stat.com/charts.html?package=%40angular%2Fcore&from=2014-11-29&to=2016-11-30 but it doesn't show any useful data... 
Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@angular/core doesn't seem to report statistics on its downloads. If you look at @angular/core on npmjs.com you wont see any stats on the right for how many downloads.

If you take a look at say, ng2-redux, you'll see that it has download statistics.

That may be why the tool that you are using doesn't work for @angular/core

Comment: Angular 2 redux on npmjs.com: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-redux

Angular 2 redux on the tool you used: